# Multiple notebooks in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interface

While working with multiple notebooks in Mathematica, is there a way to have the names of the files appear along with the minimized window of the file.
I mean that sometimes I forget which file was places where on minimizing and have not found a way to locate by name.

Comment: Hello. By files You mean notebooks?

Comment: How many notebook windows are you dealing with?

Comment: @Kuba This used to not be so much of an issue when the minimize, maximize, and close buttons were much smaller in xp and [classic windows](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzv62.png) in [Vista](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ELSX.png) the buttons are so large you can't read anything

Comment: @Liam Agree, I just wanted to be sure what OP means. About the question: In _MMA_ I always switch between NBs through `Window` menu.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Windows OS and not about Mathematica

Comment: @Kuba Yes I meant notebooks. I agree switching through Window menu is an option but wanted a more direct option like switching between tabs. The CreatePalette is a nice option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. As an alternative, you can have a palette with all the Mathematica windows for easy switching. Something like this quick hack:

```
CreatePalette[
 Dynamic@Column[
   Button[
      "WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation@#, 
      SetSelectedNotebook@#
   ] & /@ Notebooks[]]]
```

### [image]

To remove the palette window itself from the notebook list you could do the following:

```
With[{title = "Notebook selector"},
 CreatePalette[
  Dynamic@Column[
    DeleteCases[
     Button["WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation@#, SetSelectedNotebook@#] & /@ Notebooks[],
     Button[title, _]
     ]
    ], WindowTitle -> title
  ]
 ]
```

You can save the palette by selecting it and choosing "Generate Palette from Selection" from the Palette menu.

Comment: Love the hack!  (Adding another few characters.)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are on Windows.

In [Windows 7 and Vista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ELSX.png) the minimize, maximize, and close buttons are so large you can't read anything.

[image]

This used to not be so much of an issue when the minimize, maximize, and close buttons were much smaller in xp and [classic windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzv62.png).

As another solution you could shrink the minimize, mazimize and close buttons using caption buttons.

[image]

You could also switch the theme to classical windows or download [uxtheme patcher](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/UXTheme-MultiPatcher.shtml) and converting the theme to something that has smaller minimize, maximize and close buttons.

Comment: Why NotebookInformation is in red color ? Also this palette is untitled and it appears on the palette. How can this panel be saved ? Thanks!

Comment: @tchronis I'm not really sure what you mean.  Could you explain a little more?

Comment: How can i save this palette for future use? Also i would like not to contain itself...

Comment: @tchronis I think you meant to ask Sjoerd C. de Vries my question contains no palettes

Comment: @tchronis See my updated answer (indeed you were commenting below the wrong question).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the first 2-3 letters of the file name are shown on the mininmized window if you look carefully. If your multiple files have names starting differently in first 2-3 letters, you still can easily tell which is which.

[image]

Comment: Not for me in [Windows 7](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ELSX.png).  One letter isn't useful at all IMO.

Comment: I use Mathematica 9 on Window 7 Ultimate.

Comment: I check on my other PC using Mathematica 8 on Windows 7 ultimate, no letter showing at all on the minimized window. Might be related to version of Mathematica?

Comment: Yes this is probably related to Mathematica version as it does not work for me using Mathematica 7 on Windows 7 ultimate.